# Comparing text to XML value

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to have a application do the follow:
If Combobox1 text is the same as `<Name1></Name1>` in a .XML, then input "They Match" into a textbox.

This is the code I am trying anyways

```
 Dim DocList As String = "C:\Users\jefhill\Desktop"
    Dim Name1 As String
    Dim Name2 As String
    Name1 = (XElement.Load(DocList + "\parts.xml").<Name1>.Single)
    Name2 = (XElement.Load(DocList + "\parts.xml").<Name2>.Single)

    If ComboBox1.Text = Name1 Then
        DesTextBox.Text = (XElement.Load(DocList + "\parts.xml").<Des1>.Single)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = Name2 Then
        DesTextBox.Text = (XElement.Load(DocList + "\parts.xml").<Des2>.Single)
'ect
```

XML document example:

```
<Name1>Words</Name1>
<Name2>More Words</Name2>
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention the error.

> Sequence contains no elements

Comment: That's not a valid XML document - you need a single root element.  You should also really turn `Option Strict On`.  And... what is your question?  Does the code a) not compile, b) crash, c) produce the wrong results, d) something else?  Perhaps take a look at [ask].

Comment: @Mark Ya sorry, just added the error I am getting, forgot :( It compiles, but when I change the combobox to the text I am testing, it errors out with above error

Comment: No worries.  The error you are getting is coming from one of the `.Single` calls.  Based on your sample XML, there are no `<Des1>` or `<Des2>` elements in your XML, so perhaps one of those?  You should also be using `.Value` to get the string value from an `XElement` - I suppose it works as-is because `Option Strict Off` doing an implicit conversion to string.

Comment: You also don't need to be calling `XElement.Load` every time - just load the XML once and save it in a variable.

Comment: @Mark how can I call it once, but load several? Can you give me an example?

Comment: You are loading the same XML document each time - `DocList + "\parts.xml"` - so just `Dim xml As XElement = XElement.Load(DocList + "\parts.xml")` ... `Dim Name1 As String = xml.<Name1>.Single().Value` ... `Dim Name2 As String = xml.<Name2>.Single().Value`.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Mark that was exactly what I was asking, and I also got my original problem fixed - thanks. You can add an answer for credit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84224/discussion-between-dwb-and-mark).

Comment: Sorry - chat is blocked for me here, so I can't see any messages posted there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error

> Sequence contains no elements

comes from calling `.Single()` when no matching elements were found, which implies that one or more of the element names you are querying for are missing from your XML document.  Since the XML you provided is incomplete, I can't tell which that may be.  It may be a simple typo.

There are a couple of other issues in your code.  I would recommend using `Option Strict On` to avoid some of those issues.

You should only load the XML document once:

```
Dim xml As XElement = XElement.Load(DocList + "\parts.xml")
```

You should use `.Value` to get the string value for an element, since the `.Single()` will return an `XElement`:

```
Dim Name1 As String = xml.<Name1>.Single().Value
Dim Name2 As String = xml.<Name2>.Single().Value
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help Mark!